# Material-UI side menu?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I found the left side menu on the material ui demo page: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar quite appealing. However, it doesn't seem to be one of the components that material ui provided.

Is there any component library with a side menu like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to be one of the components it provided in the library"?

Comment: I mean the side menu itself doesn't seem to be one of the components that material ui provided. I'm sorry for not making it clear. I will edit it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Drawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/), is the **side-menu** component [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/) provides, so that you can use both `Drawer` and `AppBar` components together in your case I think. They have a [*Responsive Drawer* example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/) which will probably prove very helpful.

Comment: I think in the example they use `Drawer` together with the `MenuItem`. Thank you. It's clear to me now.

Comment: And what is the sub menu component?